# read parameter from file for HTTP request in SOAP UI

Tags: testing, automation, soapui

I have more than 400 test cases in SOAP UI, and now component have additional feature so i have to add 3 more parameter to each test case (HTTP request).

Is there any ways to just add any simple excel file in SOAP UI and HTTP Request read 3 parameter from that? so I can save my time and efforts.

Comment: could you provide more information and details about what it is that you are testing and how you are currently doing that testing.  It sounds like what you are wanting to do is to have a file containing a set of SOAP messages along with the expected response and to automatically send these SOAP messages to a server, get the response, and then check that the response received matches the expected response.  However please provide more information about what you have now and what you would like to have.